# ValueError: X has 1 features per sample; expecting 6209089 on uvicorn for my Sentiment analysis API

Tags: python, machine-learning, postman, fastapi, sentiment-analysis

I built a sentiment analysis model and I am trying to deploy it using fastAPI. This is my code:

```
from fastapi import FastAPI
from pydantic import BaseModel
import pickle
import json
import numpy as np
app = FastAPI()

class ModelInput(BaseModel):
    review: str  
    
# Loading the saved model
sentiment_model = pickle.load(open('sentiment_analyzer_new.sav', 'rb'))

@app.post('/sentiment_prediction')
async def sentiment_pred(input_parameters: ModelInput):
    
    rev = input_parameters.review  
    
    input_list = [rev]
    
    # Reshape the input data to have a shape of (1, -1)
    input_array = np.array(input_list).reshape(1, -1)
    
    # Print for debugging
    print("Review Text:", rev)
    print("Input Array Shape:", input_array.shape)
    
    predictions = sentiment_model.predict(input_array)
    
    # Assuming 'predictions' is an array of predictions
    if predictions[0] == 1:
        sentiment = 'Positive'
    else:
        sentiment = 'Negative'
    
    response = {
        "Review": rev,
        "Sentiment": sentiment
    }
    
    return response
```

But when I test with postman with the JSON

```
{
    "review": "This is a positive review."
},
```

I keep getting `internal server error` and when I check the terminal, this is the error I'm getting:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "c:\users\user\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\uvicorn\protocols\http\h11_impl.py", line 408, in run_asgi
    result = await app(  # type: ignore[func-returns-value]
  File "c:\users\user\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\uvicorn\middleware\proxy_headers.py", line 84, in __call__
    return await self.app(scope, receive, send)
  File "c:\users\user\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\fastapi\applications.py", line 289, in __call__
    await super().__call__(scope, receive, send)
  File "c:\users\user\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\starlette\applications.py", line 122, in __call__
    await self.middleware_stack(scope, receive, send)
  File "c:\users\user\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\starlette\middleware\errors.py", line 184, in __call__
    raise exc
  File "c:\users\user\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\starlette\middleware\errors.py", line 162, in __call__
    await self.app(scope, receive, _send)
  File "c:\users\user\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\starlette\middleware\exceptions.py", line 79, in __call__
    raise exc
  File "c:\users\user\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\starlette\middleware\exceptions.py", line 68, in __call__
    await self.app(scope, receive, sender)
  File "c:\users\user\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\fastapi\middleware\asyncexitstack.py", line 20, in __call__
    raise e
  File "c:\users\user\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\fastapi\middleware\asyncexitstack.py", line 17, in __call__
    await self.app(scope, receive, send)
  File "c:\users\user\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\starlette\routing.py", line 718, in __call__
    await route.handle(scope, receive, send)
  File "c:\users\user\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\starlette\routing.py", line 276, in handle
    await self.app(scope, receive, send)
  File "c:\users\user\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\starlette\routing.py", line 66, in app
    response = await func(request)
  File "c:\users\user\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\fastapi\routing.py", line 273, in app
    raw_response = await run_endpoint_function(
  File "c:\users\user\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\fastapi\routing.py", line 190, in run_endpoint_function
    return await dependant.call(**values)
  File "C:\Users\USER\Desktop\Sentiment analysis\api.py", line 28, in sentiment_pred
    predictions = sentiment_model.predict(input_array)
  File "c:\users\user\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\sklearn\linear_model\_base.py", line 307, in predict
    scores = self.decision_function(X)
  File "c:\users\user\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\sklearn\linear_model\_base.py", line 286, in decision_function
    raise ValueError("X has %d features per sample; expecting %d"
ValueError: X has 1 features per sample; expecting 6209089
```

Please, what am I doing wrong, and how can I resolve it?

At first, I was getting an error to resize which I did with the `input_array = np.array(input_list).reshape(1, -1)`

But now, I'm getting a new error.

I just want to be able to successfully test the API with postman and not get an error.

Thanks a lot.

Comment: How did you build your model? What code was used to evaluate it? I very much doubt your model is really designed to expect 6209089 features. (If you've been following a tutorial, linking to that can also be helpful.)

Answer (score 1):

You should probably read : [ValueError: X has 29 features per sample; expecting 84](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57438375/valueerror-x-has-29-features-per-sample-expecting-84)

It seems your input does not have the format expected by the model. Printing it will probably help you understand it's current shape.

From what we see, your input is a string "class ModelInput(BaseModel): review: str"

Then input_list is a list of one string "input_list = [rev]"

Then reshaped to a list of list of string. This is most probably not what you want.

[image: example of similar handling]